# If window width > 1080 then this - else, revert to css and check on resize AND page load

Tags: jquery, html, css, if-statement, window-resize

I am making a section in a page, the height is set using `screen.availHeight` which does exactly as I need but I also need it so that when the width is below 1080px the height is set back to the default in the css, I have tried a few things but it will not work, the `if` statement I am using checks and will only use the `screen.availHeight` if the width is above 1080px as it should, but when it is then reduced back down again, it will not reset.

Also, I need it to check when the page is loaded as I am using `(window).resize` - is there a way to use both `(window).resize` and `(document).ready` so that it checks the width on load up but also when resized?

```
<script>
$(window).on('load resize',function(){ //Amended line which now works
    if ($(window).width() > 1080)
    {
        var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;
        $('#home').css('height', screenHeight + 'px');
    }
    else
    {
        $('home').css('height', '');
    }
});
</script>
```

Here is a demo of the page - http://zimxtrial.ukbigbuy.com/

If you try loading the page with the browser under 1080px width, it is fine, then resize above 1080px, still fine, then resize down, you see problem one, then refresh the page at above 1080px and you see problem two. This is my first project using javascript so I may be missing something simple.

The first issue is now solved - does anyone know how to make `else` revert to css?

Comment: this should be done in CSS, check [`min-width`](http://devdocs.io/css/min-width) and [`max-width`](http://devdocs.io/css/max-width)

Comment: Hey Tristan, did you get a solution to your 2nd problem, i.e. revert to css, I am having same issue right now and dont know what to do?

Comment: @whyAto8 - Unfortunately I never did find a solution, I ended up with a bit of a re-design.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .on() to bind a function to multiple events:

```
$(window).on('load resize',function() {

    ...

});
```

Or just pass the function as the parameter to normal event functions:

```
var myFunction = function() {

   ...

}

$(window)
    .load(myFunction)
    .resize(myFunction)
    .click(myFunction)
```

Comment: Thank you, that has sorted out one problem but the second, bigger problem still remains, any idea on how to revert back to css on `else`?